# How to sort a text file with strings and integers

Tags: c#, bubble-sort, insertion-sort

I have recently been trying to make a code that sorts my text file into a text box, like a leader board. I have been trying to sort it by the high score or just alphabetically

[image: this is how the text file is saved]

How would I sort these using an insert or bubble sort?

Comment: You could look up an algorithm for bubble sort or insertion sort then implement it in your code.  You could also use built-in methods like `Array.Sort` or `OrderBy`.  Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, please show your attempts or read [ask]

Comment: if you are in C # why insert or bubble sort  when C# have extension sort method that sort

Comment: Create a class or struct with properties from the file for example (it is json, make the same in C#) - ScoreData `{ name: '', score:0 }` and then load your file using `File.ReadAllLines` and deserialize each line into a `ScoreData` object. You'll get an array like this `ScoreData[]` that you can sort normally using `scoreData.OrderBy(x => x.Score)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort something you have to break the data into an object that holds the individual parts in separated properties. Then you write an comparer for the kind of objects and apply that comparer.

Example with Comparer class:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var rawData = @"Guest 450
Ryan 300
Ryan 4850
Ryan 100
Guest 300
Guest 1800";

        var players = rawData
            .Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(row => row.Split())
            .Select(elements => new Player { Name = elements[0], Score = int.Parse(elements[1]) })
            .ToList();

        players.Sort(PlayerComparer.Default);

        foreach (var player in players)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(player);
        }
    }
}

public class PlayerComparer : IComparer<Player>
{
    public static readonly IComparer<Player> Default = new PlayerComparer();

    public int Compare(Player x, Player y)
    {
        if (x == null)
            return -1;

        if (y == null)
            return 1;

        var scoreComparison = y.Score - x.Score;

        if (scoreComparison != 0)
            return scoreComparison;

        return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(x.Name, y.Name);
    }
}

public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"{Name} {Score}";
}
```

Depending on your needs you can also replace the usage of the comparer class with a LINQ query:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var rawData = @"Guest 450
Ryan 300
Ryan 4850
Ryan 100
Guest 300
Guest 1800";

        var players = rawData
            .Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(row => row.Split())
            .Select(elements => new Player { Name = elements[0], Score = int.Parse(elements[1]) })
            .ToList();

        var sortedPlayers = players
            .OrderByDescending(player => player.Score)
            .ThenBy(player => player.Name);

        foreach (var player in sortedPlayers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(player);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why even bother with the first solution? Why not LINQ all along ? My +1 for the 2nd solution

Comment: @SergeWautier: If the comparison is more complex and you like to encapsulate it in one place and use it on multiple, then the comparer class makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
string path = "C:\\Users\\file\\Desktop\\test.txt";
string delim = ' ';

  string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
  List<Tuple<string, int>> users = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();

  foreach (string line in lines)
  {
    string[] keyValue = line.Split(delim);

    users.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(keyValue[0], int.Parse(keyValue[1])));
  }

  // sort by users
  users.Sort((x, y) => y.Item1.CompareTo(x.Item1));

  // sort by scores
  users.Sort((x, y) => y.Item2.CompareTo(x.Item2));
```

The error handling for int.Parse and line.Split has been left out.

Method2:

```
  string path = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.txt";

  // sorted scores
  var sortedPlayersByScores = File.ReadAllLines(path)
                                  .Select(line => line.Split(' '))
                                  .Select(elem => new 
                                   Tuple<string, int>(elem[0], int.Parse(elem[1])))
                                  .OrderBy(x => x.Item2);

  // sorted players by name
  var sortedPlayersByName = File.ReadAllLines(path)
                                .Select(line => line.Split(' '))
                                .Select(elem => new 
                                 Tuple<string, int>(elem[0], int.Parse(elem[1])))
                                .OrderBy(x => x.Item1);
```